# Searching for help to learn

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, xml

I'm started to study by myself informatics, beginning with html and css and keep going to reach real programming languages. Sometimes I fell like lost while i'm learning and studying something, so I was looking for suggestions about references, about software to use, (now i'm learning on w3schools and sololearn) or books. thanks again to all!

Comment: Imho w3schools is terrible and i tried to find a way to blacklist it for my personal google results on multiple occasions. I don't know of good javascript books, but would look at university courses about javascript, the lecturers often list books they think are good and/or fit their course well. Always hard to find good books.

Comment: this is not the place to ask questions like this so prepare to get down voted. But since I know how hard it is to get started here some Ideas: What is your goal? HTML,CSS is web development. Do you want to become a Webdeveloper? Because "real programming languages" like C# or JAVA are not mainly used to produce websites. So you maybe want to look into Software Development. If you want to keep that path wit Web-developement I would highly recommend "FreeCodeCamp" the course covers all topics and starts at the bottom but you can also skip modules.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thank for your kind reply! As I know going to school ( it's early for me now university yet) it's the better choice and it will be what i'll do, but as you know another great way to learn is right here, talking with others and hearing people experiences and their suggestion, so I thought would been a good idea listening on a community :)

Comment: @hansTheFranz thank you for your honest reply and kindness! I know that I will can face unfortunately people less kind than you that have replied so far, but this doesn't matter, I care learning and reaching my goals that are learning html (and his related markup language like xml xhtml) right to build an idea that I have got for a website; but also, I wanna learn real programming languages as the ones you mentioned to extend my knowledge for others ideas!

Comment: @user8275141 please check out FreeCodeCamp you will learn a lot and there is a clear path on what to learn. While doing the course you will build up a portfolio since they give you projects. The community is very helpful and you can gather multiple certificates which can be helpful when you are searching for a Job.

Comment: I would suggest you focus on one aspect at a time.  Start by learning HTML only.  Become familiar with the tags, headings, etc.  Learn what the tags are used for and what context each should be used.  Don't worry about what it looks like.  Then learn CSS.  Pure CSS, no LESS or SASS or anything that does some of it for you.  It's important to know what should be produced before you start using tools like that.  Once you have a solid base where you can create a page and control its layout then start learning javascript.

Comment: edx.org (there's the excellent CS50 course) and coursera.org offer free online courses form top universities. I recommend starting with freecodecamp or codecademy, though, because it's easier for beginners. Like hansTheFranz said, it all comes down to what you want to learn. For Web development (basically: making websites), you need to know at least some HTML, CSS and JavaScript (not to confuse with Java!). If you want to be a programmer for the Web, learn JavaScript, if you don't want to learn too much code learn JQuery or a CMS like Wordpress.org

Comment: @hansTheFranz the community it's ever helpful as you said! Totally agree! 
I'm signed on freecodecamp already and yes, it is so rich of contents and help! :)

Comment: @Russell totally right and I totally agree! Now this is my goal! Reaching the right and perfect knowledge of these two fundamental markup language. But sometimes when I told to myself I wanna learn and studying correctly on html for example, I faced points where also if not wanted, css is come out and then all my" line" or "map" of studying is jumped.

Comment: @user8275141 Do you already know what you want to learn? For example, making webapps, dealing with databases or making powerful software? I always recommend for beginners to start with the Python or JavaScript programming languages. If you're inclined to do things for the Web, Javascript is the better option. Otherwise, I'd personally choose Python. I strongly advise you NOT to start with a difficult language like C or even Java

Comment: @Russell what you suggest to not face anymore this issue? Or at least avoiding it as much as possible?

Comment: @flen now I want to study to learn languages that allow me to build a website. I wanna also learning languages to make others things, like apps, but it is not my first purpose now. At the moment, I want to study and learn languages to build a website, also if my concept it's so ambitious, then I think that php and other programming languages will be required, but meanwhile I have to start studying from the base, and once learned correctly starting with another one language or also asking help for my purpose to who has already the knowledge that I haven't yet. I felt to share my purpose :)

Comment: @flen I don't knew codecademy, so curious to do a look! I want to develop my own concept of website, so I have decided to learning and studying html, css and JavaScript (also I need php, but one thing at time). I confused honestly Java and JavaScript!

Comment: @user8275141 My personal advice then is to ditch PHP for the while, go straight to JavaScript, learn its basics. After that, learn HTML and CSS. JavaScript is becoming a powerful language being applied for many different things (controlling the server with Node.js and making desktop apps with Electron). After you have a solid base front-end web development (Javascript, HTML, CSS), you'll want to dive in the back-end (servers, databases, and other stuff needed to make a really interesting website). Learn JavaScript first, it will open many doors for you

Comment: @user8275141  I would just play around with HTML.  I know it sounds silly, but things like making list.  Looking at how the same text behaves in a div, span, and p tags.  The default behavior of img, and header tags.  Where header tags should be used and their semantic meaning.  There's a lot you can learn just by opening an HTML file on your desktop and adding stuff to it.  You don't need to spend weeks on it, an hour a day for a week would have you better prepared to start controlling the layout with CSS.  When you get distracted don't worry too much about it.  It happens to all of us.

Comment: @Russell your reply make me encouraged! Mostly when you talk about being confused sometimes! But make me a bit more confused hearing to jump to JavaScript, I thought html e css were more important to study before JavaScript right to understand it, or anyway that html was at the start of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w3schools is good for beginners, try to apply all examples,
and you can learn from https://www.tutorialspoint.com it's so rich of valuable information.

Also, you can read newest articles publish daily in https://css-tricks.com/
and https://tympanus.net/codrops/

regards

Comment: really thank you for suggestions! I'll surely watch link you given me now! Thanks again!

Comment: w3schools has outdated information and advises some bad coding practices, but in general it's fair enough to start learning there. Just keep in mind it is not an authoritative source of information, there might be (gross) mistakes

Comment: And there we go. Opinions on the quality of off site ressources. Exactly the reason why such question as this are not appreciated here.